# SharePoint column formatting using JSON - RAG status lights with text, how to get it align properly?

Tags: json, sharepoint

I've almost got this working but I just need a bit of help with the formatting of the column.  I have a SharePoint list with a text column, the data that is entered into this column is a version number.  The JSON creates a red/amber/green circle based on the version number i.e. less than 6.4 = red, 6.4-6.9 = amber and 7+ = green. I've also kept the text value so this shows within the circle, as you can see here. [SharePoint RAG column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1jUZ.jpg)

The issue I have is I can't get the circle or text to centre on the column, as you can see from my code below I am cheating by using padding, this gets the circle where I want but the text is still jammed up against the left of the column. As you can tell my JSON is a bit ropey so any help would be gratefully received.

```
{
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "attributes": {},
  "style": {
    "position": "absolute",
    "left": "30%",
    "top": "15%",
    "color": "black",
    "width": "40px",
    "height": "35px",
    "border-radius": "100%",
    "background-color": {
      "operator": "?",
      "operands": [
        {
          "operator": ">",
          "operands": [
            "[$Software_x0020_version]",
            "6.9.9"
          ]
        },
        "#00b300",
        {
          "operator": "?",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": "<",
              "operands": [
                "[$Software_x0020_version]",
                "6.3.9"
              ]
            },
            "#ec1313",
            "#ffcc00"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "children": []
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this would help you.
[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "@currentField",
      "attributes": {},
      "style": {
        "position": "absolute",
        "left": "30%",
        "top": "15%",
        "color": "black",
        "text-align": "center",
        "width": "40px",
        "height": "25px",
        "border-radius": "100%",
        "background-color": {
          "operator": "?",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": ">",
              "operands": [
                "[$Software_x0020_version]",
                "6.9.9"
              ]
            },
            "#00b300",
            {
              "operator": "?",
              "operands": [
                {
                  "operator": "<",
                  "operands": [
                    "[$Software_x0020_version]",
                    "6.3.9"
                  ]
                },
                "#ec1313",
                "#ffcc00"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Update:

Updated format:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "@currentField",
      "attributes": {},
      "style": {
        "position": "absolute",
        "left": "30%",
        "top": "15%",
        "color": "black",
        "text-align": "center",
        "width": "40px",
        "height": "35px",
        "align-items":"center",
        "display":"inline-grid",
        "border-radius": "100%",
        "background-color": {
          "operator": "?",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": ">",
              "operands": [
                "[$Software_x0020_version]",
                "6.9.9"
              ]
            },
            "#00b300",
            {
              "operator": "?",
              "operands": [
                {
                  "operator": "<",
                  "operands": [
                    "[$Software_x0020_version]",
                    "6.3.9"
                  ]
                },
                "#ec1313",
                "#ffcc00"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Cool, that's much better than I had achieved, now if it was possible to push the text down that would be perfect....

Comment: I'm back on this one, when a field is blank it is being populated by a red circle, I am assuming this is because the third operator block is saying anything less than 6.3.9 should be red.  Is there an easy way to make it so when a field is empty no colour circles are created?